# One button that starts game and is used to tap, timer skips one second at start

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am making a simple tap game and there is a count down timer and a tap area.

My aim is that you tap the "tap area" to start the game and continue to tap to score points.

At the moment when you tap there is a delay and then the timer skips from 30 to 28 quickly then carries on fine.

I know it must be something to do with my buttonpress if statement but i can't think of a better way to run my method "startGame" only the once when you press the button initially then not again till the game is reset.

here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed{

    if (started == 0){

        [self startGame];
        [tapToStart setHidden:YES];
        started = 1;
    }

    count++;

    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];

    [buttonBeep play];
    [buttonBeep setVolume:0.3];

- (void)startGame{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(subtractTime)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [backgroundMusic setVolume:0.3];
    [backgroundMusic play];
    [resetbtn setHidden: NO];
}
```

If anything else is needed let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about starting the timer at 32 or 31? It would give the appearance of a 30 second timer

Comment: The music and a timer beep start at 30 seconds you see, exactly the time when someone presses the button to start, i think that way would mean there is an actual 2 second delay once they press the button to start for the music and timer to start. Don't think that will work for my i'm afraid, thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start the background music earlier?
Maybe the file is not loaded and this causes the delay.

```
[backgroundMusic setVolume:0.3];
[backgroundMusic play];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(subtractTime)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

[resetbtn setHidden: NO];
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply! I will try this evening and get back to you!